# nginx rewrite translates some special characters

Tags: regex, nginx

I found many answers but none of them was helpful to me.
I sue nginx 1.14.0.
The problem is i get from the world link with path:

```
localhost:8070/name/Johny%20Malkowtich/city/Schwedt%5COder
```

That i want to transform into query string:

```
localhost:8070?name=Johny%20Malkowtich&city=Schwedt%5COder
```

I do this with simple rewrite like:

```
rewrite ^/name/(.*)/city/(.*)/$ https://$host?name=$1&city=$2 redirect;
```

But ng-inx translates this into:

```
localhost:8070?name=Johny%20Malkowtich&city=Schwedt/Oder
```

What is not working and is bad.

I made simpel workarund but i am not happy with that:

```
rewrite ^/name/(.*)/city/([^/]*)/(.*)/$ https://$host?name=$1&city=$2%5C$3 redirect;
```

Do you know how I can change nginx config not to translate taht one specific special character.

Comment: This: /name/(.*)/city/(.*) Works fine for me with your original replacement.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to stop Nginx rewrite module from decoding the parameters unless you re-compile Nginx with 3rd party modules. See this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/551751/how-to-explicitly-apply-percent-escapes-to-a-url-in-nginx

Comment: @PoulBak Hi, so for u the %5C is not translated into / or \ in result url?

Comment: Well I haven't tried with nginx, may be there's something special going on as @357up suggests.